# Inverse of the function $f(\theta) =\exp(i\theta)$ is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inverse-function, borel-measures

Let $\Lambda$ denotes the circle in the Complex plane, that is $\Lambda:=\{\exp(i\theta): \theta \in \mathbb R\}$. Now consider the function $f:[0,2\pi) \to \Lambda$ defined by the assignment
$$f(\theta)=\exp(i\theta),~~\text{for all }~ \theta \in [0,2\pi).$$
Now notice that $f$ is continuous and also bijective. Let $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $f$. I want to show that $f^{-1}$ is Borel measurable. Please help me to solve this. Means, how can I show that inverse image of an open set under $f^{-1}$ is Borel. Thank you.

Comment: @Lorago I want to show $f^{-1}$ is Borel, not $f$ is Borel. It is clear that the continuity of $f$  will imply $f$ is Borel, but what about $f^{-1}$?

Comment: The inverse can be written as something like $\theta = \atan(y/x)$, where $\atan$ is a piecewise function involving $\arctan$, and is measurable.

Comment: The inverse function $g$ can be written explicitly as follows: 

$g(e^{i\theta})=\theta$ if $\theta \neq 2\pi$ and $g(e^{i\theta})=0$ if $\theta =2\pi$.

Comment: @geetha290krm How can I show the inverse function $g$ is Borel measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $[0,2\pi)$ and $C_n =C \cap [0,2\pi-\frac 1 n]$. Then $C_n$ is compact and $C =\bigcup_n C_n$. Since $f$ is continuous it follows that $f(C)=\bigcup_n f(C_n)$ is a countable union of compact sets, hence a Borel set.  For any open set $U$ in $[0,2\pi)$  we have $(f^{-1})^{-1} (U)=f(U)=[f(U^{c})]^{c}$ which is Borel since $U^{c}$ is  closed in $[0,2\pi)$.